# Lines are being added which weren't made

Tags: git, atom-editor

I'm having  a wierd issue when using Git with Atom.

If I edit a few characters in a string, it actually ends up saying the change is something like: +131, -131. When I check the lines changed in SourceTree, its adding a load of spaces which wasn't done.

Here is the file without any changes done yet:

[image]

Here is the file with a change that isn't saved yet:

[image]

Now when I've hit saved:

[image]

You can see at first only one line was highlighted as being changed, but when I hit save - a load of other lines have appeared to change.

This is annoying because when I go to commit my changes, its not a true representation of what I've changed.

[image]

What could I be doing wrong here?

Comment: Could you provide an example of the error? The way you have described the problem is not very clear

Comment: "When I check the lines changed in SourceTree, its adding a load of spaces which wasn't done." -- *Adding* a load of spaces? That would be extremely odd. If it's *removing* a load of spaces though, it wouldn't surprise me if the editor has a "auto-remove trailing whitespace" setting.

Comment: @hvd yeah i've added a screenshot of the lines its adding. Wierdest thing is the lines stay exactly the same in Atom...

Comment: @MichaelWilson It's not adding any lines. You have exactly as many lines shown in red as shown in green. It's changing lines. What the change is is impossible to tell from the screenshot.

Comment: Are there any spaces or is there any indentation on the lines? We get this sometimes where a file which is tab indented is edited by someone who's editor is configured for space indentation.

Comment: Can you show us the same file open in Atom?

Comment: those look like whitespace changes... maybe your editor is changing spaces to tabs, or the other way around, or maybe removing extra whitespace at the end of the line. You need to check your editor's configuration if you don't want this to be made without you explicitly saying so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default setting for Atom is to remove any trailing whitespace you may have had. This is a sensible default for new files where it *prevents* exactly the confusion you're seeing now. For existing files, it's a bit problematic, since the first time you edit an existing file, you'll see a lot of changes.

You can either accept this setting, preferably cleaning your whole repository in a single commit, and continuing from there, or you can disable the whitespace removal: in Edit, Preferences, Packages, Whitespace, Settings, Remove Trailing Whitespace can be unchecked.

Comment: Thats seems to have dramatically stop it, thank you! Only i'm still getting other unmade changes http://i.stack.imgur.com/4hy7W.png

Comment: @MichaelWilson That's another setting in the same package, "Ensure Single Trailing Newline". With much of the same benefits and drawbacks as "Remove Trailing Whitespace".